# writing pexpect like program in c++ on Linux

Tags: c++, python, linux, pexpect

Is there any way of writing pexpect like small program which can launch a process and pass the password to that process?
I don't want to install and use pexpect python library but want to know the logic behind it so that using linux system apis I can build something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use "expect". It is very light weight and is made to do what youre describing.

Answer (score 0):

For very simple cases, [empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) is one option. It's a lightweight C program, and it can be used straight from a shell script and doesn't require Tcl.

For Debian/Ubuntu, the package is `empty-expect`.